# Could not find artifact after replication from JFrog Cloud to JFrog Cloud

Tags: maven, artifactory

I recently started a push based replication from my current JFrog Cloud account to a new JFrog Cloud account. However, after that the repositories in my local release and snapshot started throwing this error while building any project that uses them. Could someone please check and advise as to what else should I look for in order to resolve/debug this issue.

```
$ mvn clean install -P artifactory -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.mydomain.myproj:mainproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building mainproject 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/apiclient/0.43/apiclient-0.43.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain.myproject:apiclient:jar:0.43 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/thirdparty-client/0.7/thirdparty-client-0.7.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain.myproject:thirdparty-client:jar:0.7 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/interference-sdk/0.16/interference-sdk-0.16.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain.myproject:interference-sdk:jar:0.16 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/roger-client/0.3/roger-client-0.3.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain.myproject:roger-client:jar:0.3 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from snapshots: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-snapshot-virtual/com/example/myteam/sprin-param/2.0.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from snapshots: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-snapshot-virtual/com/example/myteam/sprin-param/2.0.5-SNAPSHOT/sprin-param-2.0.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain.myteam:sprin-param:jar:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/apiclient/0.43/apiclient-0.43.jar
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/thirdparty-client/0.7/thirdparty-client-0.7.jar
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/interference-sdk/0.16/interference-sdk-0.16.jar
Downloading from central: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual/com/example/myproject/roger-client/0.3/roger-client-0.3.jar
Downloading from snapshots: https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-snapshot-virtual/com/example/myteam/sprin-param/2.0.5-SNAPSHOT/sprin-param-2.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.618 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-13T19:57:44+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mainproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydomain.myproj:mainproject:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.mydomain.myproject:apiclient:jar:0.43, com.mydomain.myproject:thirdparty-client:jar:0.7, com.mydomain.myproject:interference-sdk:jar:0.16, com.mydomain.myproject:roger-client:jar:0.3, com.mydomain.myteam:sprin-param:jar:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mydomain.myproject:apiclient:jar:0.43 in central (https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/myproj-mvn-release-virtual) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Also, I can see that the JARs have been copied along with the POM to the new account.

Comment: What do you see in the Artifactory logs? It can be due to various reasons, starting with permissions of the user on the new instance, wrong credentials on the maven settings.xml  etc. Could you please share what you see in the artifactory-request.log right after you get the error?

Comment: Thanks @Ariel for the help. It happened as "Force Authentication" was not enabled on the virtual repositories.